# Send file to a VPS without uploading

Tags: networking, upload, digital-ocean, firewall, nat

I have a very slow upload speed and need to transport a large file to my VPS (Ubuntu 16). **Is it possible to do without uploading**, i.e. I would turn my PC (Windows 10) into a server and just download it on the VPS? My PC is behind a NAT and firewall so I'm not sure how to create a secure tunnel. This may show a lack of understanding of networking, but I'm asking just in case it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set up a secure server on my PC and use wget to download the file on my VPS but it seems that I'm still constrained by my upload speed since the data has to physically leave my computer, even though it looks like I'm only downloading.

I guess there is no way to bypass upload speed restrictions.